# Having to apply interface twice with forwardRef Typescript definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If I do not apply `WidgetArgs` below, I get the error:

```
~         [tsserver 2345] [E] Argument of type '({ field, value, onChange,                
~         disabled, ...rest }: { [x: string]: any; field: any; value?: any;               
~         onChange?: () => void; disabled: any; }, ref: Ref<HTMLSpanElement>) =>          
~         Element' is not assignable to parameter of type                                 
~         'ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLElement, WidgetArgs>'.                            
~           Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.                       
~             Type 'PropsWithChildren<WidgetArgs>' is not assignable to type '{ [x:       
~         string]: any; field: any; value?: any; onChange?: () => void; disabled:
```

But it does not make sense to me because I am already typing `WidgetArgs` at `forwardRef<HTMLElement, WidgetArgs>(AddressZip);`.

Why am I having to apply WidgetArgs twice when `forwardRef<HTMLElement, WidgetArgs>(AddressZip);` should be enough?

```
    type WidgetArgs = { 
      field: string;
      value: string | null;
      onChange(e: any): void;
      disabled: boolean;
      [rest:string]: any;
    }
    
    const AddressZip = ( 
      {
        field,
        value = null,
        onChange = () => {},
        disabled,
        ...rest
      }: WidgetArgs, // SEEMS LIKE THIS SHOULD NOT BE NEEDED 
      ref: Ref<HTMLSpanElement>,
    ) => { 
      const [v, setV] = useState(value);
    
      function triggerChange(val: string & number) { 
        if (!isNaN(val) && reg.test(val) || val === '') { 
          setV(val);
          onChange(val);
        } 
      } 
    
      return ( 
        <span ref={ref}>
          <Input
            value={v}
            disabled={disabled}
            onChange={triggerChange}
            {...rest}
          />
        </span>
      );
    }
    
    export default forwardRef<HTMLElement, WidgetArgs>(AddressZip);
```

Def of forwardRef function:

```
function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(render: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P>): ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>>;
```

Comment: Small tip: use Number.isNaN instead of `isNaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your `ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P>` and calling `forwardRef` in two separate steps.  This means that the render function `AddressZip` is unaware of what `T` and `P` you will use when you eventually call `forwardRef<T, P>`.

You've got the inference backwards.  If you want to define your render function and then call `forwardRef` it's the render function that needs to know the `T` and `P` types.  `forwardRef(AddressZip)` can infer `T` and `P` based on the types of `AddressZip`.

You need to keep the `WidgetAreas` type on your props, but you don't need to use it on `forwardRef`.  You can just write:

```
export default forwardRef(AddressZip);
```

This export has the type:

```
React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<Pick<WidgetArgs, string | number> & React.RefAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>>
```

---

If you want to assign the types to `forwardRef` then you would need to declare the render function inline.  This gets proper inference on the `props` and `ref`:

```
export default forwardRef<HTMLSpanElement, WidgetArgs>((
    {
        field,
        value = null,
        onChange = () => { },
        disabled,
        ...rest
    },
    ref
) => {
...
```

Comment: Oh.... is the issue with wanting to assign the types to forwardRef because I am using a function pointer instead of inline?

Comment: If you do it inline then you can assign the types to `forwardRef` and not to the props.  If you do it with a separate function pointer that is defined outside of the `forwardRef` then you have to assign types to the props because it is not aware of the `forwardRef` types.